# Bubbling action event with custom Object from component to controller using Morris.js graph in Ember component

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm implementing a basic Ember Component which will render a Morris.js line graph. I need to listen to the click event on morris and pass it to the action.

```
App.ProgressGraphComponent = Ember.Component.extend(
{
    graph: null,

    tagName: 'div',

    renderGraph: function()
    {
        this.graph.setData(this.get('progress'));

    }.observes('progress'),

    didInsertElement: function()
    {
        var element = this.get('element').id;

        var self = this;

        this.graph = new Morris.Line(
        {
            element: element,
            xkey: 'date',
            ykeys: ['amount', 'increase'],
            labels: ['Amount', 'increase'],
            resize: true,
            smooth: false,
            parseTime:false

        }).on('click', function(i, row){

            self.set('clicked', row);
            self.sendAction('goToSession');

        });
    }

});
```

In my controller, when the `goToSession` event is triggered, it passes in the `component` object. I'd prefer it if it just passed in the `row` object.

Is this the correct way to bubble the `action` up with the `row` parameter?

Answer (score 1):

It might be more preferable to send the row object with the action itself. Ember.js components allow sending actions with arguments included. For example:

```
this.sendAction('goToSession', row);
```

Which translates to something like this in the action (that either exists in the controller or route):

```
actions: {
  goToSession: function(row) {
    // manipulate morris row
  }
}
```

Learn more about sending actions outside of a component in the [Ember.js components guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/components/sending-actions-from-components-to-your-application/).

Comment: Wow, thanks. I've updated my code to look like this: https://gist.github.com/bobbysciacchitano/11129608 Is there a reason why sendAction requires a property name of the component instead of just specifying the action name to trigger in components?